# Concatenate two DataTables

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have two DataTables

DataTable1:

```
id  name
--  ----
1   jhon
2   peter
```

DataTable2:

```
city     country
---      -------
Sevilla  Spain
Granada  Spain
```

The id is corresponding. I need to concatenate the columns of these datatables.

This is the desired result:

```
id  name   city     country
--  ----   ----     -------
1   Jhon   Sevilla  Spain
2   Peter  Granada  Spain
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: maybe tell us which query-type you are using? entity-framework or pure sql? or whatever other?

Comment: how shall the records of the two tables be combined? Row 1 from table 1 to row 1 from table 2 or is there a key column that both tables share?

Comment: I need to do in c#, not in sql

Comment: the type of variable is DataTable

Comment: @user2024475 please include all columns to your table snippets

Comment: The DataTable are variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your DataTable names are "DataTable1" and "DataTable2" , you could merge them in DataTable1 by using following code;

```
Datatable1.Columns.Add("city", typeof(string));
Datatable1.Columns.Add("country", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < Datatable1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Datatable1.Rows[i][2] = DataTable2.Rows[i][0].toString();
    Datatable1.Rows[i][3] = DataTable2.Rows[i][1].toString();
}
```

Comment: looks nice, but wouldn't that be easier in database construction?

Comment: I think that it its my solution. I can try. Why "ConvertSafe"? I have an error with this function.

Comment: @user2024475 Yep sorry, it was my own class you could use .toString() also. I edited my answer now you can check that

Comment: @Vogel612 yes it is more "proper" way. But merge of two datatable is not a bad thing sometimes.

Comment: @Berkay it just seems so dumb to me: Create 2 tables. then add Table 2 to Table 1. Save Table 1 and 2. From now on use table 1 the whole code and then... thats it.

Comment: @Vogel612 I dont have and area for describe that but in some cases you  could use one datatabe for other work and second datatable for other (list of names , or list of just places in this cases). And sometimes you may need to merge both of them and show those (Thing of a method that just prints dataTable). You may face it in your future work as I did.

Comment: @Berkay but in this case i think a JOIN statement and a simple one to many relationship would be somewhat more viable as it's saving a sh*tload of memory in larger tablecompositions.

Comment: @Vogel612 yes but what if you have to show those tables seperatly ? One for the list of the users , second for the places that where your users are living for example? You have to break them in any case. You can't know the purpose of the question asker.

Comment: @Berkay but a JOIN statement achieves exactly that: Table 1 still shows all the users (and now has one additional column location) and Table 2 still shows all locations (but does not double them anymore for each user and does not even need further columns) then you go: `SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.location = Table2.id`

Comment: @user2024475 Have you tried the revised answer of mine ? I don't get any feedback from you thats why I am asking.

Comment: It is well, but I think that using linq is more elegant

Answer (score 0):

You need to add primary key to table2, and add a relationship between both of the tables.

Comment: stop. not necessary, also not really helpful if he just uses sql without any entity framework (even though you maybe guess that right ;))

Comment: Why? How add a relationship?

Comment: @user2024475 again: which kind of database are you using, do you have a database model in your project, where is the database stored?

Answer (score 0):

use below code.

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "--YOUR CONNECTION STRING--";
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select DataTable1.id,DataTable1.name,DataTable2.city,DataTable2.country from DataTable1,DataTable2
";
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Best luck !

Comment: Wrong, it is not sql - "I need to do in c#, not in sql – user2024475"

Comment: hey Berkay, how could I know that!
You should mention this in your question.

Comment: Yes , I know, thats why I give a chance you to develop your answer instead of giving -1 to you.

Comment: Thanks for that.
I had reformatted my answer. Might it help you, you can give me +1 now!!

Comment: Firstly, this is not my question, secondly he just want to merge two dataTable so, still your answer is not valid. Try to just answer the question by using c#. If you can't it is more proper to delete answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use marge  method of DataTable class

Comment: Wrong, there is no common column in two datatables

Answer (score 0):

You can take benifit of linq

1. cast your data table in IEnumerable
2. Then you can apply linq over it.

   ```
   var results = from myRow in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
   var results2 = from myRow in DataTable2.AsEnumerable()

   var result3= from row1 in results
                 join row2 in results2
                  select new
                 {
                     row1.id,
                     row1.name,
                     row2.city,
                     row2.country
                };
   ```

Comment: you did not really do that did you? just add linq to tags to be able to post an answer using linq...

Comment: @Vogel612 Yes I did  as I think it should be.

Comment: sorry to tell you, but you should not make people use things they do not understand. would you have looked below the question you might have seen, that this guy has no idea what Entity Framework is. and that is elementary pretext to linq. thus adding linq to the tags was totally inappropriate and not worthy of a 2k rep user

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't agree with you that a people don't have knowledge of `EF` does not have idea of `linq` as myself only have elementary idea of `EF`

Comment: @Vogel612 as far a `2K` rep user is concern I can get there easily. In a day or so. :)

Comment: mmmm it is very interesting and elegant. How I can cast result3 to DataTable?

Comment: @user2024475 would you be so kind to tell us what exactly you want to do with the result, maybe a conversion to DataTable is needless

Comment: @krshekhar but at least you have some (even if small) knowledge of `EF`, but C# does not necessarily make LINQ